# php session data lost after login

Tags: javascript, php, session-variables

After user logins, data is posted into **login_db.php** file consisting following code
        which checks the login and stores it into session variables.
        depending on login type the self.location line takes it to irrespective location.

In each location1.php ,location2.php, and loction3.php session_start is written in first line of each file.

```
<?php
extract($_POST);
include_once 'login/utils/conn.php';
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['login']))
{ 
     $name = $_POST['name'];
     $password = $_POST['password'];
     $sql = "SELECT ad_pk,ad_uname,ad_pwd,ad_type FROM adminlogin WHERE ad_uname ='$name' AND ad_pwd ='$password'";
     $result = mysql_query($sql);

     if($res = mysql_fetch_array($result))
     {  
        //print_r($_POST);exit;
        if ($res["ad_type"] == 'telecall') 
        {
            $_SESSION["ad_uname"] = $res["ad_type"];
            $_SESSION["adminid"] = $res["ad_pk"];
            echo $dt=date("Y-m-d",time());
            $pk=$res['ad_pk'];
            $uk=$res['ad_uname'];
            echo  $sql_ins_log = "insert into login_info(user_id,user_name,login_date)values('$pk','$uk','$dt')";
            $result_log = mysql_query($sql_ins_log);
            echo "<script>self.location='location1.php';</script>";
        }
        else if ( $res["ad_type"] == 'admin') 
        {
            $_SESSION["ad_uname"] = $res["ad_type"];
            $_SESSION["adminid"] = $res["ad_pk"];
            echo $dt=date("Y-m-d",time());
            $pk=$res['ad_pk'];
            $uk=$res['ad_uname'];
            echo  $sql_ins_log = "insert into login_info(user_id,user_name,login_date)values('$pk','$uk','$dt')";
            $result_log = mysql_query($sql_ins_log);
            echo "<script>self.location='location2.php';</script>";

        }
        else if ( $res["ad_type"] == 'bussuser') 
        {
               $_SESSION["ad_uname"] = $res["ad_type"];
               $_SESSION["adminid"] = $res["ad_pk"];
               echo $dt=date("Y-m-d",time());
               $pk=$res['ad_pk'];
               $uk=$res['ad_uname'];
               echo  $sql_ins_log = "insert into login_info(user_id,user_name,login_date)values('$pk','$uk','$dt')";
               $result_log = mysql_query($sql_ins_log);
               echo "<script>self.location='location3.php';</script>";
        }
        else
        {
                echo "<script>alert('Incorrect username or password');self.location='login.php';</script>";
        } 
    } 
}
?>
```

Here i can see session data on print_r($_SESSION);

After self.location is executed control goes to 3 different pages.
At the start of page the session_start line is written.
 Still the session data is lost and Access denied message is displayed on login.

```
<?
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE ^ E_WARNING);
//echo "helllooo".$_SESSION["ad_uname"];
print_r($_SESSION);// line returns empty array

if($_SESSION["ad_uname"]=='telecall')// if type of logged in user telecall show a different form
{
?>
   // some form displayed and further actions executed.
<? 
} 
else
{
   echo "<script>alert('Access Denied');self.location='login.php';</script>";
}
?>
```

The session id seems to change.. dont know why.can anyone guide me where i am going wrong? and why is the session_id returning 2 different ids on  the login_db.php file and the location1/2/3.php files?

Comment: the problem still persists after shifting session_start to the start of login_db.php

Answer (score 0):

`Session_start();` needs to be the first thing on the page. Looks like that's not the case on your first piece of code, and so the data never makes it into the session variable: you aren't losing the session data, you just never put it there in the first place.

Comment: i shifted session_start(); first line of the page in login_db.php bt the problem still persists

Answer (score 0):

```
Please add session_start at the start of the page.

if still there is a problem with sessions please check phpinfo() for php settings.

    Check session are enabled or not.

    Below are session values for default settings :- 

    **session**
    Session Support     enabled
    Registered save handlers    files user sqlite
    Registered serializer handlers  php php_binary wddx

    Directive   Local Value Master Value
    session.auto_start  Off Off
    session.bug_compat_42   On  On
    session.bug_compat_warn On  On
    session.cache_expire    180 180
    session.cache_limiter   nocache nocache
    session.cookie_domain   no value    no value
    session.cookie_httponly Off Off
    session.cookie_lifetime 0   0
    session.cookie_path /   /
    session.cookie_secure   Off Off
    session.entropy_file    no value    no value
    session.entropy_length  0   0
    session.gc_divisor  100 100
    session.gc_maxlifetime  1440    1440
    session.gc_probability  1   1
    session.hash_bits_per_character 5   5
    session.hash_function   0   0
    session.name    PHPSESSID   PHPSESSID
    session.referer_check   no value    no value
    session.save_handler    files   files
    session.save_path   \xampp\tmp  \xampp\tmp
    session.serialize_handler   php php
    session.use_cookies On  On
    session.use_only_cookies    Off Off
    session.use_trans_sid   0   0
```